# Get Filepath and Filename with one click on file icon

Tags: clipboard, filepath

I'm new to Python. I was curious if there's a way to simplify getting a file path concatenated with a file name (and extension for file type). I'm constantly having to not only copy the file path to my clipboard but I would also like it to get the file name and extension with a click of a button. Is this possible?

For example, I would like to be able to point and right click on a file icon and get its name and path auto-copied onto my clipboard. Would there be a way to make this happen easily with a simple Python script or is there a program out there that does this? Ex: "C:\main\ExDoc1A.docx" would be copied to my clipboard with one click of that file's icon.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, you can right click the file while holding down the shift key, then choose copy the full pathname.

If you still want a more direct approach, maybe a resource management software like [Directoty Opus](https://www.gpsoft.com.au/), or a file search software like [listary](https://listary.com) could help. Support shortcut key to copy file's full path.

Certainly Python also could do this, you need skilled in using `ctypes` module and write a lot of code, not worth it and the important thing is I won't either.